# A text where The Blessed One calls "a monk" a 'householder'?

Tags: pali-canon, terminology

I recall reading a text where Buddha addressed a supposed monk saying "householder".

If i recall correctly, the monk said that he wasn't a householder and Buddha explained the meaning of that.

I am pretty sure it's in the pali canon and am looking for the text.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've found it, mn54. Remembered it wrong.

> Potaliya the householder, while
> walking and wandering for exercise, wearing full dress with parasol
> and sandals, also went to the grove, and having entered the grove, he
> went to the Blessed One and exchanged greetings with him. When this
> courteous and amiable talk was finished, he stood at one side. The
> Blessed One said to him: “There are seats, householder, sit down if
> you like.”
>
> When this was said, the householder Potaliya thought: “The recluse
> Gotama addresses me as ‘householder,’” and angry and displeased, he
> remained silent.
>
> A second time the Blessed One said to him: “There are seats,
> householder, sit down if you like.” And a second time the householder
> Potaliya thought: “The recluse Gotama addresses me as ‘householder,’”
> and angry and displeased, he remained silent.
>
> A third time the Blessed One said to him: “There are seats,
> householder, sit down if you like.” When this was said, the
> householder Potaliya thought: “The recluse Gotama addresses me as
> ‘householder,’” and angry and displeased, he said to the Blessed One:
> “Master Gotama, it is neither fitting nor proper that you address me
> as ‘householder.’”
>
> “Householder, you have the aspects, marks, and signs of a
> householder.”
>
> “Nevertheless, Master Gotama, I have given up all my works and cut off
> all my affairs.”
>
> “In what way, householder, have you given up all your works and cut
> off all your affairs?”
>
> “Master Gotama, I have given all my wealth, grain, silver, and gold to
> my children as their inheritance. I do not advise or blame them about
> such matters but merely live on food and clothing. That is how I have
> given up all my works and cut off all my affairs.”
>
> “Householder, the cutting off of affairs as you describe it is one
> thing, but in the Noble One’s Discipline the cutting off of affairs is
> different.”
>
> “What is the cutting off of affairs like in the Noble One’s
> Discipline, venerable sir? It would be good, venerable sir, if the
> Blessed One would teach me the Dhamma, showing what the cutting off of
> affairs is like in the Noble One’s Discipline.”
>
> “Then listen, householder, and attend closely to what I shall say.”
>
> “Yes, venerable sir,” Potaliya the householder replied. The Blessed
> One said this:
>
> “Householder, there are these eight things in the Noble One’s
> Discipline that lead to the cutting off of affairs. What are the
> eight? With the support of the non-killing of living beings, the
> killing of living beings is to be abandoned. With the support of
> taking only what is given, the taking of what is not given is to be
> abandoned. With the support of truthful speech, false speech is to be
> abandoned. With the support of unmalicious speech, malicious speech is
> to be abandoned. With the support of no rapacity and greed, rapacity
> and greed are to be abandoned. With the support of no spite and
> scolding, spite and scolding are to be abandoned. With the support of
> no anger and irritation, anger and irritation are to be abandoned.
> With the support of non-arrogance, arrogance is to be abandoned. These
> are the eight things, stated in brief without being expounded in
> detail, that lead to the cutting off of affairs in the Noble One’s
> Discipline.”
>
> “Venerable sir, it would be good if, out of compassion, the Blessed
> One would expound to me in detail these eight things that lead to the
> cutting off of affairs in the Noble One’s Discipline, which have been
> stated in brief by the Blessed One without being expounded in detail.”
>
> “Then listen, householder, and attend closely to what I shall say.”
> [...][mn54](https://suttacentral.net/mn54/en/bodhi?reference=none&highlight=false)